# Generated JWT gets Invalid Signature in jwt.io

Tags: r, jwt, jose

I'm trying to access a site that requires a JWT to use it's API.

So I wrote this code in order to generate it:

```
library(jose)

secret = "ed577ae6d3661fec225c24"

jwt = jwt_encode_hmac(
  claim = jwt_claim(
    exp = as.numeric(Sys.time() + 300)
  ),
  #secret = hex2raw(secret), 
  secret = openssl::base64_encode(hex2raw(secret)),
  
  header = list(
    id = "643716473b35aa003d3d6")
)
```

The resulting JWT is:

```
> jwt
[1] "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlkIjoiNjQzNzE2NDczYjM1YWEwMDNkM2Q2In0.eyJleHAiOjE2ODEzNTk5MzAsImlhdCI6MTY4MTM1OTYzMH0.qf8frkpXOGhoe3_LJF4Xls6QFlWloG5qQsAf9gSN-rM"
```

When I paste that JWT into jwt.io, I get Invalid Signature.

[image]

I've tried not encoding to 64 and I've also tried charToRaw but got the same Invalid Signature.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your secret to enter are the `7Vd65tNmH+wiXCQ=` octets. Because your code takes "ed577ae6d3661fec225c24" the hex octets, decodes them to raw, then encodes them into base64 as the secret).

[image: validated signature on jwt.io]
[image: validated signature using npmjs.com/package/jose]

Comment: Thanks Filip! I understand what you posted, think I've got it working now because I'm using the generated JWT to hit an API that requires it, and after several tries it finally worked. I've just used the hex2raw without encoding it to base64 and it seems to be working. Thanks.